# Ubuntu - change only subnet mask

Tags: ubuntu, networking

At my Ubuntu operating system I have the following networt mask set:

```
...
inet addr:192.168.186.136 Bcast:192.168.186.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
...
```

Now I will change only the Mask from 255.255.255.0 to 255.255.254.0
Is there a command in order to do this? I could not found one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change your network settings via `ifconfig` command. If you only need to change to netmask, reassign the same ip with ne new netmask.

`ifconfig eth0 192.168.186.136 netmask 255.255.254.0`.

For more information about `ifconfig` you can look at the manual page `man ifconfig`.

Comment: I used this command and gave no error. but when I reboot my machine , it did not changed. why?

Comment: The changes by this command is only temporarily till the next reboot of the machine. If you want to make it permanent, you have to edit the `/etc/network/interfaces` file and add your interface configuration there.

Comment: Should I do anything for reload?

Answer (score 0):

With the newer iproute2 the commands are:

```
ip addr add 192.168.186.136/23 dev eth0
ip addr del 192.168.186.136/24 dev eth0
```

You first add an interface with the new netmask and then delete the old interface. The order of the commands is important because if you swap them and delete the old interface first, you will temporarily lose connectivity until it is restored by the "add" command.